# How to host Nservice bus distributor project

Tags: c#-4.0, nservicebus

I recently moved into a maintenance project which is using `NServicebus` distributors and workers, the dev server has got these hosted as windows services. 
I am trying to install the same in my local dev machine.

I tried hard to install them but could not, Can someone suggest me about how I should install the distributor and/or workers into my windows services.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what version of NServiceBus you are using?

Here is some more information on [NServiceBus Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/)

There is a [Sample of using the Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/samples/scaleout/)

To install the NServiceBus.Host you can [use command line](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/#installation)